# Accept connections only from specific subnet

Tags: c++, winsock

Using winsock I want my server app to accept connections only from a certain (let's say `192.168.0.0/24`) subnetwork.

I am thinking of two options:

- Check client's address every time I [`accept`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a connection.

  ```
  while (true) {
      SOCKET clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, 
                                   (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddress, 
                                   &addressLenght);
      if (clientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET
      || clientAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b1 != 192 
      || clientAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b2 != 168 
      || clientAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_un_b.s_b3 != 0) {
          closesocket(clientSocket);
          continue;
      }

      ...
  }
  ```
- Find out local address for corresponding network and use it as `name` argument in [`bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

  ```
  SOCKADDR_IN serverAddress;
  serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serverAddress.sin_port = htons(13666);
  serverAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.1");

  result = bind(serverSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&serverAddress, 
                sizeof(serverAddress));
  ```

What other options do I have?

P.S.: I was told that there is a better solution. But I can't figure it out.

Comment: I HOPE the addresses are in fact loaded from a configuration file, otherwise every time a network need to be restructured and hence renumbered, network managers will *"love"* you!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia yes, sure. Code above is just an example.

Comment: "I was told that there is a better solution" - but they wouldn't bother to explain at least a bit?

Comment: Also - to be clear you don't just want to accept connections on the interface that is on a particular subnet, you want the client making the connection to be on a particular subnet. It seems to me that your first example does this, but your second example will allow any client that can be routed to 192.168.0.1 to connect, even if they aren't on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want connections from the same subnet that the server is on (it's not clear from your question if that's the case or not) you can use `setsockopt()` to set the TTL to 1.  The packets for that socket (including the connection handshake) should not cross a router.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen for clients on only one subnet, the correct solution is to `bind()` a single listening socket to the local IP of the adapter that corresponds to that subnet.  Let the OS do the filtering for you.

If you need to listen for clients on multiple subnets, you can either `bind()` a separate listening socket to each subnet local IP as needed, or you can `bind()` a single socket to `INADDR_ANY` (0.0.0.0) and then filter the client's manually.

If you filter manually, you should use [`WSAAccept()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741513.aspx) instead of `accept()` so that you can utilize its `CONDITIONPROC` callback.  The difference is that when using `accept()`, clients are unconditionally accepted into the queue by the OS and are fully connected by `accept()` before your code gets access to them.  When using `WSAAccept()` instead, you get access to client remote IPs earlier and can chose whether to accept or reject individual clients before they are put into the queue to be connected.